Is it possible to implement shunt stubs to replace shunt capacitors for differential matching?
I am reviewing the subject of stub matching. For example, consider Network D:

Example photo screen-shot from TI documentation: https://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/155/3757.Differential-impedance-matching.pdf
For a series inductor, one can find an appropriate size of stub to replace a lumped inductor. But what about the capacitor in D? For single-ended, it would be an open stub to ground. I cannot think of a possible way to use an open stub for the differential topology in D.
